# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.props.QuestionApiHandler is not a function (Props has getting empty)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

> **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.props.QuestionApiHandler is not a function
> props has been empty alwas so what we can do for props
> QuestionApiHandler Call From Hear
> QuesttionApi is redux-Action**

```
import React from 'react'

class QuestionAPI extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log(props)
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
    this.state = {  
      items: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then
      ((Response) => Response.json()).
      then((result) => {
        console.log(result)// api calling sucessfully
        this.setState({ items: result })
        this.state.items.map((item) =>
          this.props.QuestionApiHandler({item:item.id}))
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  };  
}

//QuestionApiHandler call from hear
export default QuestionAPI
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { QuestionApi } from '../services/Actions/Action'
import API from '../API/QuestionAPI'
const mapStateToProps = state => ({})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    QuestionApiHandler: data => dispatch(QuestionApi(data)),
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(API)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Redux Version and Set All Container again